# Difference between request system zerorize and load factory-default in Junos?

Tags: juniper-junos

What is the difference between these commands?

Whenever I use load factory-default, I notice that my root authentication passoword and ip addresses (if not everything else too) are STILL operational.

Confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the request system zeroize media operation mode command via the CLI, you can reset the device to factory defaults. It will erase all the logs, data, and the load factory-default configuration on the device. It is the same as using the Reset Config button on the front panel on the SRX100, SRX210, SRX240, and SRX650 devices.

When the device is rebooted, it will not ask for the password and have any logs or the factory-default configuration.

The load factory-default command in the config mode will only erase the configuration and load the factory default configuration. However, you have to set the root-authentication password prior to committing the configuration.

For more info you can see:
[ https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23787 [1](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23787)